# Как сделать запрос с возможностью редактирования записей?

Tags: access, ms-access

Из разных источников с одинаковыми характеристиками данные собираются в:
- файл "Db1.mdb", таблицу "00_tbl_01";
- файл "Db2.mdb", таблицу "00_tbl_02";

Для анализа этих данных таблицы "00_tbl_01" и "00_tbl_02" подключаются как внешние таблицы в файл "Db0.mdb".
Ну и далее через запрос и т.д. См. структуру файла "Db0.mdb"

Хотелось бы находясь в любой точке схемы, иметь возможность редактирования записей из запроса.
Не удалять, не добавлять... просто редактировать...

Как сделать запрос с возможностью редактирования записей?

БД по ссылке http://transfiles.ru/4x6r1

Comment: Да хоть где спроси - запрос с UNION всё равно не станет обновляемым...

Answer (score 1):

Только копировать данные во временную таблицу, там их редактировать, а по кнопке сохранять изменения, рассовывая данные по исходным таблицам, больше никак.